# Sound problem in Pulse Audio

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, samsung

When I closed my Samsung Laptop with the audio jacked in my pulseaudio stoped working, in login screen I can see the sound icon, but when i log in to my account i can't see my indicator and can't control the volume. If i try to change sound device i can't see any device in settings but my sound works. Any ideas how to make things normal back again, i can't use my fn button to control my sound and can't switch between devices. I have tried `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio -D` k says "no such process" and D says failed. Need help